# insertNewRowBefore using phpspreadsheet not change coordinate of cell name

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

I have excel file 3 rows. I give name,`amount1` for first row first column. Third row is `=amount1+A2`.

```
200  ~ amount1
300
---
500
---
```

Now, I want to insert one row before row 1 and setValue to column 1. I have using phpspreadsheet to do this. The name, `amount1` not go together with value 200 to next row. This affect the formulae result.

```
new row  ~ amount1
200
300
---
error
---
```

The code as below:

```
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate;
$reader         =\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader("Xlsx");
$spreadsheet    =$reader->load("File1.xlsx");
$sheet          =$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->insertNewRowBefore(1);
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'new row');
$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save('File1_output.xlsx');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From getNamedRanges(), update `$range->setValue('Sheet1!$C$2');`

`Sheet1!$C$1`->`Sheet1!$C$2`

```
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate;
$reader         =\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader("Xlsx");
$spreadsheet    =$reader->load("File1.xlsx");
$sheet          =$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->insertNewRowBefore(1);
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'new row');
 foreach ($spreadsheet->getNamedRanges() as $range) {
  if($range->getName()=='amount1'){
    $range->setValue('Sheet1!$C$2');
   }

  }
$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save('File1_output.xlsx');
```